# Is there any way to verify whether given URL is a valid SharePoint List / Library Url?

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement to ask user to type in the URL of the SharePoint List or library and do validation whether that is a valid list or not. The URL could be of other site collection / subsite too. What is the best way to check if its a valid list URL and how to get the list object out of it?

Note: I can use JSOM / REST only (no server side code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming up one idea like this, create 3 input box for users, one to input site/subsite url, second input type, list/libray/folder/ 3rd input list/library/folder name, then you could add logic to check the giving information with Rest API, I think this will be suitable for this use case.

Comment: When it comes to lists, its fairly simple as you suggested. But assume that its a library inside the subsite and URL is like this

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/subsite1/documentlibrary1/

or folder

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/subsite1/documentlibrary1/folder1

How would we do it?

Comment: @NitinKhubani, you could use _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl') to check if a library or library sub folder exists.
https://sympmarc.com/tag/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl/

Comment: There is a URL and it can be a list or library. It can be in any other site collection or subsite. A list not necessarily need to have /Lists/ in it. using ListInstance module, I can even created list without /Lists/. The URL can be a Document Library or folder inside document library so there are many usecases here. above solutions seems to be fixing a single case but not the whole usecase of getting List of Library out of URL. Right?

Comment: Coming up one idea like this, create 3 input box for users, one to input site/subsite url, second input type, list/libray/folder/ 3rd input list/library/folder name, then you could add logic to check the giving information with Rest API, I think this will be suitable for this use case.

Comment: Yeah we ended up with the same logic :) thank you Jerry

Comment: Glad to hear this would be helpful to you and I will edit my original post and you could Mark as answer so that it could help others who stuck with the same question in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get the list with PnP:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items

Here is the whole lists class described:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/src/sharepoint/lists.ts

- If the request is successful, the list exists.
- If the request fails, the list doesn't exist (or another error
  occured).

Comment: Hi, this is for classic SharePoint so using these PNP JS would be difficult